# Fluid dynamics - Orientation of a mathematical plane surface

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry, orientation

The following is a problem in "Transport Phenomena" by Bird et al :

"A mathematical plane surface of area $S$ has an orientation given by  a unit normal vector $\bar{n}$, pointing downstream of the surface. A fluid of density $\rho$ flows through this surface with a velocity $\bar{v}$. Show that the mass rate of flow through the surface is $w=\rho(\bar{n}\cdot\bar{v})S$"

Certainly this plane is some flat two-dimensional plane in $\Bbb{R^3}$. The orientation refers to one of two sets of normal vectors, corresponding to the two sides of the plane. What confuses me is the "downstream of the surface" phrase. I cannot see how any surface has a "downstream". What are the relevant facts one should understand from the quote above?

Comment: As written, the expression "downstream" is meaningless.  It's possible that the surface in question is the graph of a smooth function, then "pointing downstream" could mean "pointing into the subgraph." I suggest you add details, otherwise, this question is un-answerable.

Comment: I'll add the full problem statement!

Comment: From the quote, most likely meaning is that $n\cdot v>0$, where $n$ is the normal vector and $n$ is the normal to $S$. Incidentally, the written formula for $w$ looks wrong (namely, the density function should not be a function of the inner product but of a point in the surface). My suggestion is to look for a more rigorous book on the subject.

Comment: @variations The formula does look all right if the parentheses signify multiplication of the density $\rho$ with the normal component of velocity $n \cdot v$.